# How are emails of users of this resource "stellar.stackexchange.com" compromised?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question on this resource.

Logged in through google account. My email is publicly hidden.

Not registered on other "stellar" resources.

But today I received a letter from scammers:

[image: Screenshot of email with PII redacted]

It can't be a coincidence!

Scam link: "stellar . org . il"

The sender's address is a compromised resource.

p.s. just today the topics about staking and scammers have been updated:

- [Distribuition Stella for holders](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/distribuition-stella-for-holders)
- [How the staking on stellar website works](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/4415/how-the-staking-on-stellar-website-works)
- [what is the minimal balance for staking xlm](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/4505/what-is-the-minimal-balance-for-staking-xlm)

Comment: Why do you think this site is compromised?  If it were, would not every user have received this email?

Comment: This email was in spam and it was not received by me alone.
I received a scam letter due to activity on this resource. It cannot be a coincidence.
I don’t know how, so I ask.

Comment: Personally, I suspect that it is not SE's fault.  However, I've added the "bug" tag to this, to see if we can get a view from a higher authority.